# Apache Mod Rewrite - в папке есть файл с названием из запроса

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

Не понимаю из-за чего, никогда такого не было. Например, запрос /about/ возвращает ошибку 404 Not Found, хотя у меня прописано:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Позже я заметил, что 404 выдаётся в том случаи, когда файл этот существует. В данном случаи у меня в корне лежал about.php. Например, запрос /about2/ проходит хорошо. А допустим /config/ - 404 ошибка, так как в корне config.php. Никаких настроек кроме той строчки что я написал нету. Подскажите, что это ещё за мистика, какие настройки внутри апача такое делают? Как справится? Конечно можно просто все файлы убрать из корня, но хотелось бы знать от чего так случилось.

Comment: это весь htaccess ?

Comment: В этом и странность, всё зачистил, оставил эту строку, было больше. Просто такая мистика...

Comment: при любоv раскладе, ваш index.php вызывается. без вариантов. Дальше надо смотреть, что происходит с роутингом внутри вашего приложения

Comment: А нету роутинга внутри я всё отключил я поставил exit в начале index.php Именно если имя схоже с файлом в корневом каталоге - 404 ошибка без обращения к какому-либо файлу, сразу 404

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в начале файла.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Это у меня прописано в конфигурации апача, такая же фигня